# Can't retrieve data from cloud firestore firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I send data from the activity to the cloud firestore and I retrieve it in the second activity in recycler view.
but the data doesn't appear in the second activity.

I used FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and FirestoreOptions.

This is the activity in which I retrieve the data.

```
public class MyServicesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FirebaseFirestore db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_services);

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Query query = db.collection("Services Requested");
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_my_services);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceModel> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions
            .Builder<ServiceModel>()
            .setQuery(query, ServiceModel.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ServiceModel, ServiceHolder>(response) {


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ServiceHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.service_design, parent, false);
            return new ServiceHolder(v);
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ServiceHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ServiceModel model) {
            holder.serviceImage.setImageResource(model.getServiceImage());
            Log.d("DATA", "data isn't null" + position);
            holder.serviceName.setText(model.getServiceName());
            holder.servicePrice.setText(model.getPrice() + "" + " L.E");
        }


    };


    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


}

public class ServiceHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView serviceImage;
    private TextView serviceName, servicePrice;

    public ServiceHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        serviceImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.polish_img);
        serviceName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.polish_txt);
        servicePrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_txt);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.startListening();
}
}
```

[image: Firebase cloud firestore dashboard]

This is the class model for retrieve data from cloud firestore

```
  public class ServiceModel {


private String serviceName;
private int price;
private int serviceImage;

public ServiceModel(){}
public ServiceModel(String serviceName, int price, int serviceImage) {
    this.serviceName = serviceName;
    this.price = price;
    this.serviceImage = serviceImage;
}

public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
    this.serviceName = serviceName;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public void setServiceImage(int serviceImage) {
    this.serviceImage = serviceImage;
}

public String getServiceName() {
    return serviceName;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public int getServiceImage() {
    return serviceImage;
}



 }
```

Comment: Please edit your question add the content of your `ServiceModel` class.

Comment: I added the model class

Comment: make sure that the reference name of the collection alphabet same as you are getting a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHpnx.png), that the name of the properties in the database are stored using whitespace between the words, and each word is starting with a capital letter, while in your class, there is no whitespace and the first word starts with a lower-case and the second with a capital letter. When you are using a public getter called `getServiceName()`, Firebase is looking in the database after a property called `serviceName`, which actually does not exist.

To solve this, you either change the properties in your database to match the one in the class, remove the actual data, and add a fresh one, or you can use an annotation called [PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) in front of the getter, to match the actual naming.